# Difference between removing duplicates from a list using dict and set?

Tags: python, list, performance, coding-efficiency

According to my research there are two easy ways to remove duplicates from a list:

```py
a = list(dict.fromkeys(a))
```

and

```py
a = list(set(a))
```

Is one of them more efficient than the other?

Comment: You could time them and find out. Can you give it a shot?

Comment: Performance-wise I don't think there's much of a difference, I would guess the first on has more of an overhead for the dict initialization. Also using a `set` here seems more intuitive. A good thing to do if you're doubting though is to *time them*

Comment: `timeit` analysis .`timeit list(dict.fromkeys(z))
21.4 ms ± 173 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`. where z size is a million.

Comment: `timeit list(set(z))
10.6 ms ± 463 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` where z is size of a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely the second one is more efficient as sets are more or less created for that purpose and you skip the overhead related to creation of dict which is way heavier.
Perfomance-wise it definitely depends on what the payload actually is.

```
import timeit
import random

input_data = [random.choice(range(100)) for i in range(1000)]

from_keys = timeit.timeit('list(dict.fromkeys(input_data))', number=10000, globals={'input_data': input_data})
from_set = timeit.timeit('list(set(input_data))', number=10000, globals={'input_data': input_data})

print(f"From keys performance: {from_keys:.3f}")
print(f"From set performance: {from_set:.3f}")
```

Prints:

```
From keys performance: 0.230
From set performance: 0.140
```

It doesn't really mean it's almost twice as fast. The difference is barely visible. Try it for yourself with different random data.

Answer (score 3):

in case we have a list containing `a = [1,16,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,3,9,15,7]`

and we used `a = list(set(a))` the `set()` function will drop the duplication's and also reorder our list, the new list will look like this `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,16]`, while if we use `a = list(dict.fromkeys(a))` the `dict.fromkeys()` function will drop the duplication's and keep the list elements in the same order `[1,16,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,9,15,7]`.

to sum things up, if you're looking for a way to drop duplications from a list without caring about reordering the list then `set()` is what you're looking for, **but!! if keeping the order of the list is required**, then you can use `dict.fromkeys()`

Answer (score 3):

CAUTION: since Python **3.7** the **keys of a dict are ordered**.

So the first form that uses

> list(dict.fromkeys(a))  # preserves order!!

preserves the order while using the set will potentially (and probably) change the order of the elements of the list 'a'.

Answer (score 2):

The second answer is way better not only because its faster, but it shows the intention of the programmer better. `set()` is designed specifically to describe mathematical sets in which elements cannot be duplicated, thus it fits this purpose and the intention is clear to the reader. On the other hand `dict()` is for storing key-value pairs and tells nothing about the intention.

Comment: I think this is exactly right. The second describes the _intent_ of the code. When I see that, I know exactly what the original programmer meant. The first makes me wonder if there was some particular side effect that they wanted to use, and I'd have to read it a couple of times to make sure I'm not missing anything.